# How can I expose a .NET Framework console app port in docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, frameworks, kestrel

I have a .NET Framework app that is self-hosting a kestrel (.NET Core) server. When I run this from the command line, the web-app is accessible through any browser at "http://localhost:5000/" (I can change the port if required). However, when I put this in a Docker container, I am not able to make the web app visible to the host machine.

I am using windows images in Docker. I have been able to create ASP.NET apps (for testing) that are accessible in the host machine, but I am not able to make this .NET Framework + Kestrel combination work. The code that starts the server is this:

```
            webHostBuilder.UseKestrel()
                      .UseIISIntegration()
                      .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                      .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) => { options.ListenLocalhost(port); })
                      .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: How you start container?

Comment: I am starting it with this:
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name web2 webtest`

Comment: Also, I have tested the app within the docker container, by starting a CLI and running curl:
`curl localhost:5000`, which produces the correct result.